# How to make right/left icons/text lists in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm converting an old site to a responsive site using Bootstrap, I want to find a general solution which converts all old layout format which uses tables to show icons on the left and text on the right.

So I need it to show texts regardless of the length next to icons in a list like this:

[image]

But if the width gets too small, then it should show like this:

[image]

The icon can either be a graphic, a Font Awesome character, or a word, and should always stay the same width.

But the right text width should be able to vary in length and wrap but stay left aligned to the right of the icon.

So far, I have this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">ICON</div>
  <div class="col-xs-11">This is the longer text.</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">ICON</div>
  <div class="col-xs-11">This is another the longer text.</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

But on width "lg" it breaks up:

[image]

And on width "xs" it wraps under:

[image]

How can I make it so that:

- icon column has a constant width
- text column stays to the right of the icon column but wraps its text according to width but keeps its left margin for the addition lines
- text column always stays left aligned to icon column

Comment: Have you looked at the [Bootstrap Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)?

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper that's the answer post that with an example  :)

Comment: Yes, DaniP, that is one scenario, but there are also lists in which e.g. instead of an icon, there are various words such as "yes", "no", "maybe" which have various lengths and so these should be aligned, but even in these cases, the words are quite small and I could make the icon column the width of the longest word.

Comment: Alright that is the most important requirement ... the width of first column be the width of the biggest element

Comment: @DaniP - oh, I guess that means the Media Object won't work. And I just posted my answer, crap. What about a table?

Comment: If you want always that layout ... why don't use a simple table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the [Bootstrap Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media).

```css
.
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    Here is longer text for the first list item.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    Here is even longer text for the first list item. Holy moly, this is some long text. It keeps going and going.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to solve my issue well enough for now with a mixture of words and fontawesome icons, at least the text on the right wraps nicely: https://codepen.io/edwardtanguay/pen/PzOmKQ

Comment: Glad it helped! Maybe you can set a minimum width on the left column to tidy it up: https://codepen.io/stackingjasoncooper/pen/JKOJJr